# Position submit button in header

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML like this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <header>
                <title>
                    Page title
                </title>
            </header>
            <body>    
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
                    <header class="main-header">
                        <h1>Header title</h1>
                    </header>
                <main>
                  <form action="upload">
                   <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
                   <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
                  </form> 
                </main>
             </body>
        </html>
```

Is it possible to place the submit button in line with the header (title of the page)?

As this is outside the form tags I can't just place the button within the header tags.

Can this be done with css?

Comment: no i dont think so also its a bad idea.. wont make sense logically

Comment: It may seem weird here but it makes sense for my overall goal, this is just some mock-up code...

Comment: `link` elements should only be within the `<head>` tag, which is what should come before the `<body>` tag (not `<header>` as shown in the code here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I would highly recommend not doing it this way, you can force the position of the button with css:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" style="position: absolute; top: 18px; left: 180px;">
```

By adding `position: absolute` you can set the absolute position in the window using `top` and `left`.